# Wifi speed weird

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a server located downstairs. I frequently copy disk images and movies to and from it through wifi to my desktop upstairs. However I noticed something odd.

If I copy one file (file A), it transfers at about 1.9 
 If I copy 2 files (file A and file B), file A transfers at the same 1.9 MB/S while file B transfers at about 600KB/s.

My question is why cant I transfer file A by itself at 1.9MB/s+600KB/s (2.5 MB/S) if it is obvious that both the wifi and computer can support this speed.[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of windows!

Comment: Is that Window 7 or vista because the network stack in Vista is aweful.